# Programmatically mimick @Bean method to register several instances as beans

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, spring-bean

(spring boot 1.5, java 8)

Suppose there is a Foundation, some Wall types, and Ceilings. They depend on each other, just like their physical counterparts.

This configuration class has a Foundation injected and creates Wall beans, so that Ceilings can have Walls injected. Don't mind the bad practices, I'm just trying to keep the code as short as possible without changing the essential mechanisms.

```
@Configuration
class Config {
  @Autowired
  Foundation foundation;

  @Bean
  // assume there is a lot of repetitive logic here
  WoodenWall wood() { return new WoodenWall(foundation); }

  @Bean
  BrickWall brick() { return new BrickWall(foundation); }
}
```

And a ceiling:

```
@Component
class KitchenCeiling {
  @Autowired
  WoodWall wall;
}
```

---

I'm going to be making a lot more Wall types and want them all registered as beans. Instead of having to define a `@Bean` method for each and every one of them, I want to instantiate them all in a loop and register them manually in a single go. Think of an `AllTypesOfWallsBeanFactory` if you wish.

```
@Configuration
class Config implements ??? {
  @Autowired
  Foundation foundation;

  @Override
  void addBeans(??? beanRegistry) {
    for (Class beanClass : wallClasses) {
      // instantiate BrickWall, WoodWall, etc
      registry.add(beanClass.getSimpleName(), beanClass, wallInstance);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, I can't find the right interface to implement or the right SpringBeanRegistryPostProcessorFactoryImplementationThingamajig to go to. I've tried the answers given on all the other SO posts I could find but none do the right thing.

---

One issue here is that I need the context to already be initializing beans since I need a Foundation, but I also want to add some more beans to the context so that Ceilings yet to be initialized can inject my freshly made Walls.

`@Bean` methods do exactly that: they can take dependencies that are already initialized and return new beans to be used elsewhere at the same time. I just need the programmatic equivalent to this exact mechanism.

I know dependency resolution is harder in this situation (since there isn't any reflective information for spring to figure out the total following order), but it's gotta be possible to tell spring to

1. initialize what it has dependencies for
2. process the newly created beans
3. goto 1

`BeanDefinition` doesn't fit the bill because it doesn't take any instances, and to use the factoryMethod setting I would need to make a factory class for each Wall. Back to square one.

Most of the `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` et al interfaces are called too late, don't inject the beans I give them into dependent beans (there was 1 that took *instances* but didn't do anything with them), or demand a default constructor (i.e. no dependencies). They also tend to give you objects that only take `BeanDefinition`.

In another project where there was a similar need, what ended up being used was a factory method with still a `@Bean` method for each instance it needed to produce. I'm starting to think it isn't really possible and what was done in this project is as good as it'll get.

Comment: It maybe not be totally what you're looking for, but could you have a context-scanning added to your configuration, scanning your wall package ? They will be registered all at once with correct autowiring (your foundation here)

Comment: These objects can't be instantiated by spring, it takes some custom logic from a library, that's why I need to work with a factory

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `@PostConstruct`with `ConfigurableApplicationContext`

```
@Configuration
class Config {

  @Autowired
  Foundation foundation;

  @Autowired
  ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

  @PostConstruct
  void addBeans() {
    for (Class beanClass : wallClasses) {
      ctx.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(beanClass.getSimpleName(), beanClass, wallInstance);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `implements ApplicationContextAware` with `((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).getBeanFactory().registerResolvableDependency(BrickWall.class, brickWall);` or `registerSingleton("brickWall", brickWall)` worked, thanks! I wonder what I did wrong then first time, I tried it this way before but it didn't do the trick then...

Comment: Actually this doesn't work reliably. Sometimes it does, and other times it complains a bean wasn't present. Provide that bean with a bean method, it runs. Restart it, now it complains about another bean. Smells like race conditions and the result of undefined behavior to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to conclude that it just isn't possible to do this reliably. The best one can do is making a factory method and a `@Bean` method calling the factory for each bean instance that needs to be registered. It doesn't seem possible to cut the `@Bean` methods out of the picture.